# Questions for mixed nested logit model estimation in SAS program

Tags: nested, sas, bayesian

I am trying SAS to estimate a nested logit model. I have consumers' choice dataset, and I want to estimated individual heterogeneity which is random effect and an agreement among consumers which is fixed effect at the same time.

I used Bayesian estimation process(PROC BCHOICE) to estimate a logit model, and it functioned really well and gave me proper answers. However, if I try it nested logit model with both random and fixed effect, it ignore the random effects part.

Could you give me any suggestions to resolve this problem? Is there only I have to use different software?

Sincerely,

I tried PROC BCHOICE, because I hope to estimate with Bayesian estimation procedure. Also, I have a results using PROC BCHOICE for logit model. I hope to estimate nested logit model with both random and fixed effects at the same time using bayesian estimation.